# How to periodically update Gtk3 Label text?

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I am writing an app-indicator on Ubuntu 18.04. Getting started was the most difficult part. Docs don't help much. I found [this blog](https://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html) and I have a POC that just shows a fixed text on my application bar like this -
[image]
What I have not been able to figure out is how to update this text periodically or dynamically to display actual information that I need for example: *CPU frequency, temperature* etc.

I have looked at the following places, however I think i am missing something.
https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Label.html
https://askubuntu.com/questions/108035/writing-indicators-with-python-gir-and-gtk3
https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/AppIndicator3-0.1/classes/Indicator.html#AppIndicator3.Indicator.set_label

The working code that I have is -

```
import os
import signal
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

APPINDICATOR_ID = 'myappindicator'

def main():
    indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, gtk.STOCK_INFO, appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
    indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_menu(build_menu())
    indicator.set_label('world', '8.8')
    gtk.main()

def build_label():
    label = gtk.Label()
    return label

def build_menu():
    menu = gtk.Menu()
    item_quit = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    item_quit.connect('activate', quit)
    menu.append(item_quit)
    menu.show_all()
    return menu

def quit(source):
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    main()
```

**EDIT:**
Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364460/update-a-label-in-gtk-python) similar SO post, and [this apparently working](https://askubuntu.com/a/301363/881804) example, I tried adding `timeout_add_seconds`, and `timeout_add` however the text doesn't change at all, it displays only the first call. I inserted a print statement there too, and surprisingly, that also prints **only once**. Don't know why that is happening -
New code attempt-

```
import random
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

APPINDICATOR_ID = 'myappindicator'

def cb_exit(w, data):
   Gtk.main_quit()

def change_label(ind_app):
    text = 'Hello World, what a great day'.split()
    t = random.choice(text)
    print(t)
    ind_app.set_label(t , '')

ind_app = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, Gtk.STOCK_INFO, appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
ind_app.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

# create a menu
menu = Gtk.Menu()
menu_items = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
menu.append(menu_items)
menu_items.connect("activate", cb_exit, '')
menu_items.show_all()
ind_app.set_menu(menu)
GLib.timeout_add(1000, change_label, ind_app)
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Please, read the [link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364460/update-a-label-in-gtk-python) again. It says _You should call all your methods via a timeout_ `GLib.timeout_add(ms, method, [arg])`

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev please check now. It doesn't update the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself. I was using the `timeout_add` function incorrectly. The called function must return anything non false for the timer to continue. In my case it is returning nothing, hence the timer was destroying itself. The [docs here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GLib-2.0/functions.html#GLib.timeout_add_seconds) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982843/pygtk-glib-timeout-add-how-to-tell-if-timer-not-being-destroyed) helped me figure this out. SO the code finally looks like this -

```
import random
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

APPINDICATOR_ID = 'myappindicator'

def change_label(ind_app):
    text = 'Hello world, what a beautiful day'.split()
    t = random.choice(text)
    print(t)
    ind_app.set_label(t , '')
    return True

def quit(source):
    Gtk.main_quit()

ind_app = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, Gtk.STOCK_INFO, appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
ind_app.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

# create a menu
menu = Gtk.Menu()
menu_items = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
menu.append(menu_items)
menu_items.connect("activate", quit)
menu_items.show_all()
ind_app.set_menu(menu)
GLib.timeout_add(1000, change_label, ind_app)
Gtk.main()
```