# How to set data in pyGtk label in specific time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, label, gtk3, cursor-position

In the code below I want to get Mouse's x and y position using pyauotogui library then I want to set those values into Gtk labels everytime mouse cursor move.

The code works fine to get and show the data once but when my cursor moves then there would be no change in values.

Here is my code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import pyautogui as pt


class LabelWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Taha Mouse Pos")
        self.box = Gtk.VBox(spacing=6)
        self.add(self.box)


    def get_stat(self):
        x,y = pt.position()
        self.labelx = Gtk.Label('X position: {}'.format(x))
        self.labely = Gtk.Label('Y position: {}'.format(y))
        self.box.pack_start(self.labelx,True,True,0)
        self.box.pack_start(self.labely,True,True,0)

def main():
    window = LabelWindow()
    window.set_default_size(300,100)
    window.set_resizable(False)
    window.get_stat()
    window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to periodically update Gtk3 Label text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887891/how-to-periodically-update-gtk3-label-text)

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev Hey bro, thanks for mentioning this link, I read it pretty well but finally I couldn't understand what exactly should I do with that timeout thing??

Comment: you pass it a `function`, which will be called once in a `period`